# Antrag an oder auf?

Tags: difference

I have always had this question since I started to learn German that when to use auf and when to use an . As an example I can name the word "Antrag". When to use preposition "an" and when to use preposition "auf". Can they be used interchangeably? If not, what's the difference?

For example:

> Einen Antrag **an** den Betriebsrat stellen.

or

> Einen Antrag **auf** den Betriebsrat stellen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

With *Antrag **auf*** you indicate **what** someone is applying for; with *Antrag **an*** you indicate **to whom** someone is applying for something.

So in your example, *an* is correct:

> Einen Antrag **an** den Betriebsrat stellen.

---

More examples with [*Antrag auf*](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?query=Antrag%20auf#result_container) and [*Antrag an*](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?query=Antrag%20an#result_container).

Answer (score 13):

It is Antrag auf etwas an jemanden stellen. For example you say

> Ich werde einen Antrag auf Kindergeld (what you want) an das Sozialamt (who will grant it) stellen.